# NIAttributedLabel - supporting links while keeping control tap functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'm trying to use `NIAttributedLabel` to produce a label that has both text, links and supports this behavior:

- Pressing a link will call `- (void)attributedLabel:(NIAttributedLabel *)attributedLabel didSelectTextCheckingResult:(NSTextCheckingResult *)result atPoint:(CGPoint)point;` - this works fine.
- Pressing anywhere else will call another method - if implemented, the link functionality above is lost.

I don't have to use `NIAttributedLabel` so suggestions for a better control would also work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is `NIAttributeLabel`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this finally;

1. adding function to file NIAttributedLabel.m

   ```
   -(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        // never return self. always return the result of [super hitTest..].
        // this takes userInteraction state, enabled, alpha values etc. into account
        UIView *hitResult = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

        // don't check for links if the event was handled by one of the subviews
        if (hitResult != self) {
            return hitResult;
        }

        if (self.explicitLinkLocations || self.detectedlinkLocations) {
            BOOL didHitLink = ([self linkAtPoint:point] != nil);
            if (!didHitLink) {
                // not catch the touch if it didn't hit a link
                return nil;
            }
        }
        return hitResult;
   }
   ```
2. remove all [super touch XXXX] functions in all touchXXX;

then, it works!